# What does -y mean in apt-get -y install command?

Tags: apt

I always see commands like this

```
apt-get -y install
```

What is the `-y` tag for and what is the difference between `apt-get install` with and without the `-y` tag?

Comment: the Manual is at https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get

Answer (score 232, accepted):

From the results of running `man apt-get`

```
-y, --yes, --assume-yes
           Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and
           run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as
           changing a held package, trying to install a unauthenticated
           package or removing an essential package occurs then apt-get will
           abort. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.
```

If you run an apt-get command without the `-y` option, you need to answer to all prompts that you get from that command interactively in order for the execution of the command to continue.

Comment: Also note that this is a common switch in utilities that have confirmation prompts in their functionality. While it's convenient in the shell, the real purpose is for automating scripts.

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as calling `-y` "common". The *feature* is fairly common in system administration tools (of which apt-get is one) but the *method* varies. When in doubt, **always** refer to the man page for the command in question for what parameter to use and what effect it has.

Comment: One side effect of using `-y` is that it will skip downgrades, whereas if the user entered `y`, it would perform the downgrades. So if you want `-y` to execute the same thing as a user entering `y`, you also need to add `--allow-downgrades`.