# newbie, installing unebootin packages help

Tags: 18.04

trying to install unebootin on ubuntu 18.04 after install get this:
sorry- newbie question, but do I answer y or n and can I install without them or are they necessary?  Thanks in advance,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  extlinux p7zip p7zip-full unetbootin-translations
Suggested packages:
  p7zip-rar
Recommended packages:
  gksu | kdesudo
The following NEW packages will be installed
  extlinux p7zip p7zip-full unetbootin unetbootin-translations
0 to upgrade, 5 to newly install, 0 to remove and 18 not to upgrade.
Need to get 2,107 kB of archives.
After this operation, 10.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

do I need these to install?

Comment: FYI Ubuntu 18.04 already includes Startup Disk Creator, which does the same job as unetbootin.  It's right there in Desktop Search.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does -y mean in apt-get -y install command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/672892/what-does-y-mean-in-apt-get-y-install-command)

Answer (score 2):

You must install these. Packages have often other packages as dependencies. This has the advantage that packages don't need to maintain their dependencies, e.g. if a used packages gets an update, the update is installed by the package manager and the package that uses the updated package gets the advantages of the update.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply

Comment: If you think this answers your question, be sure to tick the check mark next to it, to mark this question as "answered".